# How do I configure a Cups Linux server to allow printing from a particular IP only?

Tags: networking, share, rhel, cups

We have a printer connected to cups RHEL-7 server. There are other RHEL PCs in the network. We want to allow printing to the cups server from a particular IP only.

We have added the following line in /etc/cups/cupsd.conf

**Listen :631**
and restarted CUPS.

But when we give command **lp -h serverip
filname** from the PC for print, error message **scheduler not responding** is displayed.

We don't want to make the printer accessible to other PCs in the network.

How to achieve this.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation of CUPS](https://www.cups.org/) ? It is open source, so you could improve its code...

Comment: Yes. It says printer must be shared. If printer is shared it propagates to total network. But we want to restrict printer usage to particular IP only.

Answer (score 0):

### You could patch and improve the [CUPS](https://www.cups.org/) software, since it is open source.

Don't forget to read its [documentation](https://www.cups.org/documentation.html) (e.g. about printer classes). You probably should look into or even edit some file under `/etc/cups/`

You could use [iptables(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/iptables.8.html) to reject any connection on the port 631 (e.g. to reject on a machine *A* any connection from machine *B* to [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) port 631).

You should use [lpadmin(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lpadmin.8.html).

Read of course the [Printing-HowTO](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Printing-HOWTO/), [tcp(7)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html), [socket(7)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html), [syscalls(2)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/)

You might need to reboot both server and client (or at least restart printing services), and some spooled printing jobs might be lost.